# What is the correct term for the die with multiples of ten written on it?

Tags: dice, terminology

What is the correct term for this die? It is a standard die in any 7 dice set.

[image]

It has multiples of ten from 10 to 00 written on it (10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, (1)00).

I seem to think that it is called a 'percentile die', is this correct?

Comment: Just a quick reminder that comments aren't for chatting or mini-answers. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The two ten-sided dice used together to generate a number in the range 1-100 (or 0-99) are **percentile dice** (plural). The same term is applies to a pair of twenty-sided dice, each marked 0-9 twice, used for the same purpose.

Back in the Before Time, dice sets didn't include a die marked with double-digits; you would just roll different-colored dice, having declared one of them the "tens". I think that sometimes the specific die you are asking about is called the **tens die**; Chessex [calls it](http://chessex.com/Dice/Opaque%20Dice/25400.htm) a "Tens 10" on their website.

Comment: The "Before Time"... lol, nice.  Very well put. Hearkening from said time, that's exactly how our old ways now seem, like relics.  I vaguely remember a die with 100 sides: it was the size of a squash ball and would roll forever before landing on a side, which were so small that any slight nudge would cause it to roll another number.

Comment: @John https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zocchihedron

Answer (score 12):

The one with the multiples of 10 on it is often referred to as a "decader" die, at least on crafting sites like etsy and shapeways.

Comment: Decader is the term I've always used, too.

Comment: @Dewi May I ask where abouts that term is used, geographically?

Comment: I don't think it seems geographically limited. I'm not 100% sure, since I've not been paying much attention when it's used, but I think I've heard it used both in the UK and in Austin, TX, including by a Canadian.
So, more likely it's related to age/social group? I'm in my 40s and I'm one of the youngest in my roleplaying group: so it may be a greybeard term? But weighing against that is that I can find no evidence of its use on the net before 2009.

Comment: Given I can't find a reference for this pre-shapeways, I'm wondering if this is just a shapeways coinage which has worked its way into the collective consciousness to the point where some of us can't remember a time without it? I coulda *sworn* we called them this 20 years ago... but now I'm unsure.

Comment: I'll continue to call is a "tens" die, but +1 for teaching me a new nerdy term.

Comment: Gamescience claims a trademark on the name _Deckaider_ for this style of die. [10 sided dice at the Gamescience online store][1]

  [1]: http://www.gamesciencedice.com/D10--10-Sided-Dice-_c_17.html